# UITableView doesn't auto-resize when changing frame of tableHeaderView in iOS 6

Tags: ios

I implemented a parallax effect in a UITableView by using a tableHeaderView and resizing the frame when scrolling:

```
headerView is the table.tableHeaderView
topHeight = 400; // the height of the tableHeaderView

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (scrollOffset>=0 && scrollOffset<=topHeight) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollOffset/2, 320, topHeight - scrollOffset/2);
        headerView.frame = frame;
    } else if (scrollOffset>topHeight) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
        headerView.frame = frame;
    } else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, topHeight);
        headerView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

The effect works perfectly on iOS 5.0 and 5.1 but I get some strange space between the tableHeaderView and the table content on iOS 6+ (the header in the images is red)

iOS 5 - no space between the header and the table content:
[image: iOS 5 - no space between the header and the table content]

iOS 6 0 header is spaced from the table content:
[image: iOS 6 0 header is spaced from the table content]

Comment: I tried to recreate this issue - could you please provide more example code. What is headerView, which value has topHeight and which settings has the table view, etc.

Comment: @x2on I updated the question with some more info; no settings have been altered in the tableView from the default values (just drag-and-drop a UITableView or a UITableViewController). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the tableHeaderView again:

```
table.tableHeaderView = table.tableHeaderView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the size of the header view is fixed with the initial value. Perhaps on iOS 6 the internal calculation from the table view has changed - so the height of the view can't be changed without reloading the table.

If you reload the table at the end of the scrollViewDidScroll function it works (but it will be an performance issue).

It's the same effect manipulating the height of a cell without reloading the table.